# On scroll do this, then off scroll do this

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add/remove effects on scroll but it seems that it happens instantaneously so that nothing actually happens.

```js
 $(window).scroll(function () {
     var sticky = $('.mobile-menu-container'),
     scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

  if (scroll >= 1) sticky.addClass('fixed');
   else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
    $('.mobile-menu-container.fixed').addClass('shadow');
  }).scroll('off', function () {
    $('.mobile-menu-container.fixed').removeClass('shadow');
  });
 });
```

```css
  .mobile-menu-container{
     position: relative;
     background: green;
     height: 50px;
  }
  .mobile-menu-container.fixed{
     background: red;
  }
  .mobile-menu-container.fixed.shadow{
     box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -2px lightgray;
  }
  .container{
     height: 5000px;
  }
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <div class="mobile-menu-container>
      <div class="text">This is the header</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please provide actual question inside title and codepen or jsfiddle demo. If your question was why your scroll triggeres without scrolling, then the answer would be it's probably something else you didn't list here. I've tried your example and it works on my codespace.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your javascript function by given below. and just add CSS of `.sticky`

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
 

 html, body {
    margin:0px;
}
.mobile-menu-container {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
    height: 50px;
}
.mobile-menu-container.fixed {
    background: red;
}
.mobile-menu-container.fixed.shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 6px 2px -2px lightgray;
}
.container {
    height: 5000px;
}
.sticky {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  

<div class="container">
  <div id="myHeader" class="mobile-menu-container">
    <div class="text">This is the header</div>
  </div>
</div>
```